# Шрифт pscyr, ошибка при компиляции pdflatex

Tags: шрифты, latex, tex

пытаюсь скомпилировать следующий код

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
   Привет!
\end{document}
```

Но получаю ошибку. Вот лог

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.3.16)  27 MAR 2022 23:34
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pscyr\pscyr.sty
Package: pscyr 2001/01/28 v0.4c Cyrillic Postscript fonts as default
)
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package

(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cyrillic\t2aenc.def
File: t2aenc.def 2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
Now handling font encoding T2A ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T2A

(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t2aenc.dfu
File: t2aenc.dfu 2021/06/21 v1.2n UTF-8 support
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0237 (decimal 567)
   defining Unicode char U+0400 (decimal 1024)
   defining Unicode char U+0401 (decimal 1025)
   defining Unicode char U+0402 (decimal 1026)
   defining Unicode char U+0403 (decimal 1027)
   defining Unicode char U+0404 (decimal 1028)
   defining Unicode char U+0405 (decimal 1029)
   defining Unicode char U+0406 (decimal 1030)
   defining Unicode char U+0407 (decimal 1031)
   defining Unicode char U+0408 (decimal 1032)
   defining Unicode char U+0409 (decimal 1033)
   defining Unicode char U+040A (decimal 1034)
   defining Unicode char U+040B (decimal 1035)
   defining Unicode char U+040C (decimal 1036)
   defining Unicode char U+040D (decimal 1037)
   defining Unicode char U+040E (decimal 1038)
   defining Unicode char U+040F (decimal 1039)
   defining Unicode char U+0410 (decimal 1040)
   defining Unicode char U+0411 (decimal 1041)
   defining Unicode char U+0412 (decimal 1042)
   defining Unicode char U+0413 (decimal 1043)
   defining Unicode char U+0414 (decimal 1044)
   defining Unicode char U+0415 (decimal 1045)
   defining Unicode char U+0416 (decimal 1046)
   defining Unicode char U+0417 (decimal 1047)
   defining Unicode char U+0418 (decimal 1048)
   defining Unicode char U+0419 (decimal 1049)
   defining Unicode char U+041A (decimal 1050)
   defining Unicode char U+041B (decimal 1051)
   defining Unicode char U+041C (decimal 1052)
   defining Unicode char U+041D (decimal 1053)
   defining Unicode char U+041E (decimal 1054)
   defining Unicode char U+041F (decimal 1055)
   defining Unicode char U+0420 (decimal 1056)
   defining Unicode char U+0421 (decimal 1057)
   defining Unicode char U+0422 (decimal 1058)
   defining Unicode char U+0423 (decimal 1059)
   defining Unicode char U+0424 (decimal 1060)
   defining Unicode char U+0425 (decimal 1061)
   defining Unicode char U+0426 (decimal 1062)
   defining Unicode char U+0427 (decimal 1063)
   defining Unicode char U+0428 (decimal 1064)
   defining Unicode char U+0429 (decimal 1065)
   defining Unicode char U+042A (decimal 1066)
   defining Unicode char U+042B (decimal 1067)
   defining Unicode char U+042C (decimal 1068)
   defining Unicode char U+042D (decimal 1069)
   defining Unicode char U+042E (decimal 1070)
   defining Unicode char U+042F (decimal 1071)
   defining Unicode char U+0430 (decimal 1072)
   defining Unicode char U+0431 (decimal 1073)
   defining Unicode char U+0432 (decimal 1074)
   defining Unicode char U+0433 (decimal 1075)
   defining Unicode char U+0434 (decimal 1076)
   defining Unicode char U+0435 (decimal 1077)
   defining Unicode char U+0436 (decimal 1078)
   defining Unicode char U+0437 (decimal 1079)
   defining Unicode char U+0438 (decimal 1080)
   defining Unicode char U+0439 (decimal 1081)
   defining Unicode char U+043A (decimal 1082)
   defining Unicode char U+043B (decimal 1083)
   defining Unicode char U+043C (decimal 1084)
   defining Unicode char U+043D (decimal 1085)
   defining Unicode char U+043E (decimal 1086)
   defining Unicode char U+043F (decimal 1087)
   defining Unicode char U+0440 (decimal 1088)
   defining Unicode char U+0441 (decimal 1089)
   defining Unicode char U+0442 (decimal 1090)
   defining Unicode char U+0443 (decimal 1091)
   defining Unicode char U+0444 (decimal 1092)
   defining Unicode char U+0445 (decimal 1093)
   defining Unicode char U+0446 (decimal 1094)
   defining Unicode char U+0447 (decimal 1095)
   defining Unicode char U+0448 (decimal 1096)
   defining Unicode char U+0449 (decimal 1097)
   defining Unicode char U+044A (decimal 1098)
   defining Unicode char U+044B (decimal 1099)
   defining Unicode char U+044C (decimal 1100)
   defining Unicode char U+044D (decimal 1101)
   defining Unicode char U+044E (decimal 1102)
   defining Unicode char U+044F (decimal 1103)
   defining Unicode char U+0450 (decimal 1104)
   defining Unicode char U+0451 (decimal 1105)
   defining Unicode char U+0452 (decimal 1106)
   defining Unicode char U+0453 (decimal 1107)
   defining Unicode char U+0454 (decimal 1108)
   defining Unicode char U+0455 (decimal 1109)
   defining Unicode char U+0456 (decimal 1110)
   defining Unicode char U+0457 (decimal 1111)
   defining Unicode char U+0458 (decimal 1112)
   defining Unicode char U+0459 (decimal 1113)
   defining Unicode char U+045A (decimal 1114)
   defining Unicode char U+045B (decimal 1115)
   defining Unicode char U+045C (decimal 1116)
   defining Unicode char U+045D (decimal 1117)
   defining Unicode char U+045E (decimal 1118)
   defining Unicode char U+045F (decimal 1119)
   defining Unicode char U+0490 (decimal 1168)
   defining Unicode char U+0491 (decimal 1169)
   defining Unicode char U+0492 (decimal 1170)
   defining Unicode char U+0493 (decimal 1171)
   defining Unicode char U+0496 (decimal 1174)
   defining Unicode char U+0497 (decimal 1175)
   defining Unicode char U+0498 (decimal 1176)
   defining Unicode char U+0499 (decimal 1177)
   defining Unicode char U+049A (decimal 1178)
   defining Unicode char U+049B (decimal 1179)
   defining Unicode char U+049C (decimal 1180)
   defining Unicode char U+049D (decimal 1181)
   defining Unicode char U+04A0 (decimal 1184)
   defining Unicode char U+04A1 (decimal 1185)
   defining Unicode char U+04A2 (decimal 1186)
   defining Unicode char U+04A3 (decimal 1187)
   defining Unicode char U+04A4 (decimal 1188)
   defining Unicode char U+04A5 (decimal 1189)
   defining Unicode char U+04AA (decimal 1194)
   defining Unicode char U+04AB (decimal 1195)
   defining Unicode char U+04AE (decimal 1198)
   defining Unicode char U+04AF (decimal 1199)
   defining Unicode char U+04B0 (decimal 1200)
   defining Unicode char U+04B1 (decimal 1201)
   defining Unicode char U+04B2 (decimal 1202)
   defining Unicode char U+04B3 (decimal 1203)
   defining Unicode char U+04B6 (decimal 1206)
   defining Unicode char U+04B7 (decimal 1207)
   defining Unicode char U+04B8 (decimal 1208)
   defining Unicode char U+04B9 (decimal 1209)
   defining Unicode char U+04BA (decimal 1210)
   defining Unicode char U+04BB (decimal 1211)
   defining Unicode char U+04C0 (decimal 1216)
   defining Unicode char U+04C1 (decimal 1217)
   defining Unicode char U+04C2 (decimal 1218)
   defining Unicode char U+04D0 (decimal 1232)
   defining Unicode char U+04D1 (decimal 1233)
   defining Unicode char U+04D2 (decimal 1234)
   defining Unicode char U+04D3 (decimal 1235)
   defining Unicode char U+04D4 (decimal 1236)
   defining Unicode char U+04D5 (decimal 1237)
   defining Unicode char U+04D6 (decimal 1238)
   defining Unicode char U+04D7 (decimal 1239)
   defining Unicode char U+04D8 (decimal 1240)
   defining Unicode char U+04D9 (decimal 1241)
   defining Unicode char U+04DA (decimal 1242)
   defining Unicode char U+04DB (decimal 1243)
   defining Unicode char U+04DC (decimal 1244)
   defining Unicode char U+04DD (decimal 1245)
   defining Unicode char U+04DE (decimal 1246)
   defining Unicode char U+04DF (decimal 1247)
   defining Unicode char U+04E2 (decimal 1250)
   defining Unicode char U+04E3 (decimal 1251)
   defining Unicode char U+04E4 (decimal 1252)
   defining Unicode char U+04E5 (decimal 1253)
   defining Unicode char U+04E6 (decimal 1254)
   defining Unicode char U+04E7 (decimal 1255)
   defining Unicode char U+04E8 (decimal 1256)
   defining Unicode char U+04E9 (decimal 1257)
   defining Unicode char U+04EC (decimal 1260)
   defining Unicode char U+04ED (decimal 1261)
   defining Unicode char U+04EE (decimal 1262)
   defining Unicode char U+04EF (decimal 1263)
   defining Unicode char U+04F0 (decimal 1264)
   defining Unicode char U+04F1 (decimal 1265)
   defining Unicode char U+04F2 (decimal 1266)
   defining Unicode char U+04F3 (decimal 1267)
   defining Unicode char U+04F4 (decimal 1268)
   defining Unicode char U+04F5 (decimal 1269)
   defining Unicode char U+04F8 (decimal 1272)
   defining Unicode char U+04F9 (decimal 1273)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
   defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
   defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
   defining Unicode char U+27E8 (decimal 10216)
   defining Unicode char U+27E9 (decimal 10217)
   defining Unicode char U+FB00 (decimal 64256)
   defining Unicode char U+FB01 (decimal 64257)
   defining Unicode char U+FB02 (decimal 64258)
   defining Unicode char U+FB03 (decimal 64259)
   defining Unicode char U+FB04 (decimal 64260)
   defining Unicode char U+FB05 (decimal 64261)
   defining Unicode char U+FB06 (decimal 64262)
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T2A+faq on input line 1
12.

(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pscyr\t2afaq.fd
File: t2afaq.fd 2001/03/03 v0.4c PS font definitions for T2A/AntiquaPSCyr
))
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
)
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2022/02/26 3.73 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count193
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@unhyphenated=\language84

(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count194

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
babel
)
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-russian\russianb.ldf
File: russianb.ldf 2021/01/10 1.3m Russian support for the Babel system
Language: russian 2020/09/09 1.3k Russian support for the Babel system
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 124.
Package babel Info: Default for \cyrdash is provided on input line 163.
)
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'canadian' set to \l@english
(babel)             (\language0). Reported on input line 102.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'australian' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language78). Reported on input line 105.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'newzealand' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language78). Reported on input line 108.
))
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count195
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
(document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T2A/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T2A+cmr on input line 8
.
(C:\Softwares\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cyrillic\t2acmr.fd
File: t2acmr.fd 2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \th on input line 8.
[1

{C:/Users/Dmitry/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (document.a
ux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2463 strings out of 478544
39708 string characters out of 2852787
335046 words of memory out of 3000000
20703 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
471103 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
40i,5n,52p,186b,204s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file faqr6a): Font faqr6a at 720 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Содержание miktex-makepk.log

```
2022-03-27 23:34:10,432+0300 INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (27804) started by pdflatex in directory C:\Study material\Колебания и волны (ТКВ)\test with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose faqr6a 720 600 magstep(1.0)
2022-03-27 23:34:10,436+0300 INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font faqr6a at 720 DPI...
2022-03-27 23:34:10,443+0300 INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2022-03-27 23:34:10,449+0300 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2022-03-27 23:34:10,449+0300 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose faqr6a
2022-03-27 23:34:10,450+0300 INFO  miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose faqr6a
2022-03-27 23:34:11,375+0300 INFO  makepk - Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...
2022-03-27 23:34:11,375+0300 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -q -t faqr6a
2022-03-27 23:34:11,375+0300 INFO  miktex-makepk.core - start process: miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -q -t faqr6a
2022-03-27 23:34:12,494+0300 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font faqr6a could not be created.
2022-03-27 23:34:12,494+0300 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font faqr6a could not be created.
2022-03-27 23:34:12,494+0300 FATAL miktex-makepk - Info:
2022-03-27 23:34:12,494+0300 FATAL miktex-makepk - Source:
2022-03-27 23:34:12,494+0300 FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2022-03-27 23:34:12,505+0300 INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (27804) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: В версиях miktex за последние год-два автор сломал работу пакета pscyr. Преднамеренно или случайно - я не разбирался. Способы лечения я тоже не искал, просто перешел на TeX-Live. Вообще, если Вам от PSCyr нужна только гарнитура Литературная (по умолчанию в pscyr включается именно она), то можно поставить пакет `literat` (на CTAN есть) - эта гарнитура в миктехе еще работает.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.